# adb command doesn't work after installing anaconda

Tags: android, linux, adb

I am working on Android Thing. Anyway, this command has the following problem:

$ adb connect Android.local
adb: /home/cocadas/anaconda2/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by adb)
unable to connect to Android.local:5555

If I do 
$ adb
adb: /home/cocadas/anaconda2/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by adb)
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.32

any suggestion?

Comment: seems like a machine problem rather than an android things problem: http://askubuntu.com/questions/830466/libcrypto-so-1-0-0-no-version-information-available-required-by-ssh

Answer (score 0):

My case is special in that I took over the Raspbarry PI with Android thing image from a colleague.

So when Raspberry boots up, it shows the content of the app but not ip address. To resolve the problem, I did two things:

first, it is to resolve the libcrypto.so.1.0.0 problem by 
$mv /mylocation/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 /mylocation/libcrypto.so.1.0.0_bk

second, to figure out ip address. Connect Ubuntu ethernet to the router. Connect Raspberry PI ethernet to the same rounter. Reboot the Raspberry PI, connect keyboard to Raspberry. Hit ESC key once. It backs to the homepage. There you can see the ip address. In Ubuntun, do
$add connect .